# Is this smart or no?

Tags: php, sql-injection

Is it ok to use this code to trim and escape all post´s in my register function? or is it better practice to trim and escape each and every inputs

```
// Trim and sanitize our input
$_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);
$_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);

if (invalidinput) dostuff
else insert into user (username,passwd) values ('{$_POST['username']}','{$_POST['passwd']}')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, because:

1. It doesn't work for multi-dimensional arrays.
2. You might not use every single `$_POST` value as a DB parameter and thus 3).
3. It can be unnecessarily slow.
4. `mysql_real_escape_string()` might need the `$link_identifier` argument.

Point #1 can be worked out with a custom recursive function, at the expense of being even more slow.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You shouldn't be escaping in the first place. You should be using bound parameters.

Comment: I certainly prefer bound parameters as well, but as long as you're doing something to properly escape your SQL input, there's no harm in not using them.